# Объединение 2-х dataframe с разным кол-вом столбцов по условию

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

вроде бы банальный вопрос, но не могу решить проблему с объединением 2-х датафреймов с разными кол-вом колонок.

```
 Df1:
    Рег.номер  Возраст компании
    123            5
    456            3.5
    789            7
    987            4
    654            3

DF2:
Рег.номер   Возраст компании Год банкротства  
123               5               2017
654               3               2018
```

Цель прибавить к первому датафрему DF1 второй Df2 и получить следующий результат:

```
DF1:
Рег.номер  Возраст компании  Год банкротства  Статус банкрот 
    123            5              2017            1
    456            3.5                            0
    789            7                              0
    987            4                              0
    654            3              2018            1
```

Решение мне кажется таким банальным, но у меня выходит полная ерунда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
In [190]: d1.merge(d2, on=['Рег.номер'], how='left')
Out[190]:
   Рег.номер  Возраст_компании_x  Возраст_компании_y  Год_банкротства
0        123                 5.0                 5.0           2017.0
1        456                 3.5                 NaN              NaN
2        789                 7.0                 NaN              NaN
3        987                 4.0                 NaN              NaN
4        654                 3.0                 3.0           2018.0
```

или так:

```
In [192]: d1.merge(d2.assign(Возраст_компании=d2['Возраст_компании'].astype('float32')), on=['Рег.номер','Возраст_компании'], how='left')
Out[192]:
   Рег.номер  Возраст_компании  Год_банкротства
0        123               5.0           2017.0
1        456               3.5              NaN
2        789               7.0              NaN
3        987               4.0              NaN
4        654               3.0           2018.0
```

---

**UPDATE:**

```
res = (d1.merge(d2.assign(Возраст_компании=d2['Возраст_компании'].astype('float32')),
                on=['Рег.номер','Возраст_компании'], 
                how='left'))
res['Статус_банкрот'] = res['Год_банкротства'].notna().astype(int)
```

Результат:

```
In [203]: res
Out[203]:
   Рег.номер  Возраст_компании  Год_банкротства  Статус_банкрот
0        123               5.0           2017.0               1
1        456               3.5              NaN               0
2        789               7.0              NaN               0
3        987               4.0              NaN               0
4        654               3.0           2018.0               1
```

Comment: А Колонку "Статус_банкротства" потом через np.where сделать и combine_first?

Comment: У меня в релаьном датафреме на самом деле 190 колонок и если при merge будет создаваться дубликат колонок в виде _x и _y, совсем туго будет после чисттить :(